# Como sacarle al textarea las lineas de la parte inferior derecha

Tags: html, css

queria saber como saquerle al textarea las lineas que tiene por defecto en la parte inferior derecha, que propiedad de css tengo que usar?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esta es una captura de un textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con CSS:

```
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

Ejemplo:

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio!